# Silverlight issues on firefox and chrome

Tags: silverlight

I have one wmv file hosted on virtual directory in IIS 6.0.

When we play this movie with our silverlight player using IE streaming and buffering it works but when I open the same movie in Firefox the movie does not play.

I just want to know is there something specific with silverlight related to browser which should be handled

Answer (score 0):

I think the resoun is some browsers behave differently for mime types. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediafailed(v=vs.95).aspx

Register the media element's MediaFailed event if it is your app. This may show more details. Maybe instead of stream a page or message returning to you as I faced of previously.

```
<MediaElement MediaFailed="eventhandler" .../>
```